# how to customize zoneupdater mixin for jquery slider in tapestry

Tags: jquery, ajax, tapestry

I had seen example of jQuery range slider from tapestry5 jquery docs.but i had tried using zoneupdater mixin by creating a jquery slider i didn't get how to pass min amd max values in the url,i want to know how it could be done using zoneupdater mixin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are referring to this [ZoneUpdater](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/onevent) from jumpstart.

This mixin assumes that you using plain tapestry/prototype. If you are using tapestry-jquery, you will need to do something similar to [Bind](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/mixins/docsbind).

I think you'll need to tweak the Bind mixin slightly to pass the current clientside slider value(s) to the serverside event. You will probably append request parameters to the event URL which you can access in the serverside event via `@RequestParameter` or `Request.getParameter()`.